# Problems accessing public method of another class

Tags: java

I currently use two classes, `ircBot(extends pircbot`) and `ircRobotti(extends Robotti)`.

I'm trying to compile the class files on a shell but i'm getting an error:

> ./ircBot.java:26: cannot find symbol symbol  : method lisaaJonoon(int)
>   location: class Robotti
>                                   annaRobo().lisaaJonoon(suunta);

`lisaaJonoon()` is defined in `ircRobotti` and it's public.

Any ideas what might cause the error?

Comment: need more codes where you are accessing this function ?

Comment: Make sure that lisaaJonoon() takes int as an argument.

Comment: The error might be caused by the fact that the compiler can't find the symbol lisaaJonoon(int) in class Robotti. That's just a guess, as you posted no code...

Comment: Btw, the classe names do not follow Java naming conventions, and I feel the same way towards method readability.

Answer (score 1):

`lisaaJonoon(int)` has a parameter of type `int` which is different from `lisaaJonoon()`.

Comment: Forgot to mention lisaaJonoon(int suunta) is the form how it's determined.

Answer (score 1):

A public method from one class will be accessible in other class if you make sure that

1: Both classes are in same package. If they are in different packages then you need to import the class whose method you are calling.

2: The class whose method is being called, should also be compiled.

3: Make sure, method signatures are same as in called method. (i.e. the number of arguments an d their type)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but as you are compiling on a shell you're probably not setting the classpath correctly. How are you invoking javac?